# Docker link to previously started containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'd like to carry out a one shot `docker-compose run` that will run against some previously started containers. My docker-compose.yml file will look like this:

```
one_shot_service:
 ...
  links:
    - long_running_service:docker
long_running_service:
  ...
```

My workflow is:

1. Start the long running service
   `docker-compose up long_running_service`
2. Run the one shot service multiple times. `docker-compose run --no-deps one_shot_service`

When I do this the `/etc/hosts` file on the `one_shot_service` does not contain an entry for docker. When I run without `--no-deps` it's fine. The reason I don't want to run without `no-deps` is beause the `long_running_service` takes a long time to start up.

So long story short, how can I link to existing containers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`external_links` directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links).

Example:

```
external_links:
    - long_running_service:your_alias
```

Comment: how did I miss that! Thanks Chris.

Comment: For me it throws, resolution error:
ERROR: for wordpress  Failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp: lookup logstash on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host

Comment: `127.0.1.1` > `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Note: For version 2 file format, the externally-created containers must be connected to at least one of the same networks as the service which is linking to them.